# Synthpop disco song, retro 80s vibe, British accent, German name

Tags: pop, synthpop

I remember listening to a song on YouTube a few years ago:

- The song had a 80s vibe but I don't think it was actually from the 80s.
- The singer was male, tall, and blond or ginger. He reminded me very much of Patrick Wolf.
- He was singing in a small indoor studio-setting.
- I think the singer had a British accent
- His name may have been somewhat German-sounding and maybe starting with "W".
- The song itself was sung in English,
- pop/synth/disco,
- about love, excuses, blame or something along these lines.
- There may have been a few dancing and singing backup ladies as well but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Wolfsheim - find you here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNczZ99bMe8) ? Or something else from Wolfsheim?

Hits a lot of your list points quite well.